# Php class parse xml to html form like joomla

Tags: php, html, xml, joomla

anyone know php class to parse xml to html form like joomla

Ex

Xml writen

```
<field id="city" name="title" type="City" label="Choice you city"
    description="this is city field"
    required="true" />
```

html output

```
Choice you City
<select name="title" id="city">
      <option>....</option>
      ..................

</select>
```

Comment: If Joomla can do this, why not just grab the code from Joomla?

Answer (score 1):

AS Gordon said - Why not using the Joomla method for it?

However, I do not know how Joomla implements it and where the value attribute or the data for each option entry come from but this following example should give you an idea. The data is set as content of the XML node "field".

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<form>
<field id="city" name="title" type="select" label="Choice you city" description="this is city field" required="true">City1,City2,City3</field>
<field id="postcode" name="title" type="text" label="Choice your Postcode" description="this is postcode field" required="false" />
</form>
XML;

$form = new SimpleXMLElement ( $xmlstr );


foreach ( $form->children () as $field ) 
{
    $required = ( $field['required'] == 'true' ) ? 'required' : null;
    $label = ( $field['label'] ) ? $field['label'] : null;

    switch( $field['type'] ) {
        case 'select':

            if (isset ( $field ) && $field != '') 
            {
                echo $label;
                echo '<select name="'.$field['name'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" '.$required.'>';

                $data = explode ( ',', $field );
                foreach ( $data as $value )
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                }
                echo "</select>";
            }
        break;

        case 'text':
            echo $label;
            echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['name'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" '.$required.' />';
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Choice you city
<select name="title" id="city" required><option value="City1">City1</option>
  <option value="City2">City2</option>
  <option value="City3">City3</option>
</select>

Choice your Postcode
<input type="text" name="title" id="postcode"  />
```

Example in a [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56b4ad219623b561e5c428588e6e235cd27dc310)

I hope this will help you.